# Апелляция - происхождение 2х л

Tags: орфография

Почему в слове апелляция два л, в то время как в английском 2 п, appeal?

Answer (score 2):

Слово образовалось от лат. appellatio, а в нём две буквы Л.

Comment: Спасибо, Екатерина. Осталось понять почему в русском потерялась вторая П.

Comment: Пожалуйста! Да, это действительно интересно, и вопрос заслуживает отдельной страницы.

Comment: А  почему  в  английском  потерялась  вторая  Л ?